# ExtJS grid filter automatically creating the list of possible options from the data in the store

Tags: java, extjs, extjs4

There is a `Store` defined:

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    autoLoad: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    model: 'Project',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/project/list',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
    },
    remoteSort: false,
    remoteFilter: false
});
```

that is used by the `grid panel`:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    columns: [{
            dataIndex: 'option',
            text: 'Option',
            filter: {
                type: 'list',
                store: optionStore // how this should be defined?
            }
    }], // many columns with 'list' filters 
    features: [{
        ftype: 'filters',
        local: true
    }]
});
```

Once the data is loaded from the server all the operations (sorting, filtering) are performed locally. All the values displayed in the columns are from a fixed set of values, so the filters' type is `list`. Is it possible to automatically generate filters from the values in the store (`myStore`)?

---

Suggested solution:

```
columns: [{
    dataIndex: 'name',
    text: 'Name',
    filter: {
        type: 'string'
    }
}, {
    dataIndex: 'client',
    text: 'Client',
    filter: {
        type: 'list' // caused the filtering to be disabled
    }        
}, {
    dataIndex: 'domain',
    text: 'Domain'
}]
```

Comment: Take a look at [Ext Grid MultiSearch Plugin](http://extjs.eu/software/ext-grid-multisearch-plugin/). The filter fields there are highly configurable so the above would be matter of 2-3 lines of code.

Comment: @Saki thanks for the reference. If I may suggest how to improve your site and increase the conversation rate, it would be great to see some actual code samples because after reading the features of this plugin and I am not convinced that it will actually address the problem I have.

Comment: I'll post a screencast on how to use the plugin soon. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `myStore` is store of the grid right? If so, add this method to it:

```
,getUniqueValues:function(field) {
    var  me = this
        ,results = {}
    ;

    me.each(function(record){
        var value = record.get(field);
        results[value] = {};
        results[value][field] = value;
    });

    return Ext.Object.getValues(results);
} // eo function getUniqueValues
```

Now, listen to `myStore` load event (if it is remote) and call `getUniqueValues` in the listener passing the field name you want the unique values from. Having the unique values array, you can do whatever you want to do with it, e.g. load to a combo, use as list for grid filter, etc.

Of course you can modify the format of the returned data by changing the method itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, especially since you're referring to `myStore` as the grid's store, but in your grid code you're using `store` and then again there's `optionStore`, which does not seem to be defined anywhere (It seems you've taken that from the ExtJS examples).

Anyway, if I understand your question correctly, you want to have the `ListFilter` populated automatically based on the data from the grid?

Referring to the documentation of the [`options`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.filter.ListFilter-cfg-options) or [`store`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.filter.ListFilter-cfg-store) configuration properties:

> If neither store nor options is specified, then the choices list is
>   automatically populated from all unique values of the specified
>   dataIndex field in the store at first time of filter invocation.

it should be enough to omit these properties to achieve the desired result:

```
columns: [{
    dataIndex: 'option',
    text: 'Option',
    filter: {
        type: 'list'
        // omit 'options' and 'store' configuration
    }
}]
```

**EDIT:** Provided a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wKSG/)

Comment: Thanks Matt. Tried it, but it does not work. Actually it causes filtering to be disabled at all. I have edited the question with the code I have used.

Comment: Actually I tried it by modifying the example from the ExtJS 4.2 library and it worked for me. Unfortunately I couldn't set up a working fiddle, since SenchaFiddle/JSFiddle does not include the `Ext.ux.*` classes for the grid filter plugin. Will check tomorrow if I can come up with a working fiddle somehow.

Comment: Adam, I've edited my answer and provided a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wKSG/), which demonstrate the behaviour as described above.